# I need a filter for 3 letters instead of 1 letter I've written the above line for 1 letter filtter so need to alter for the 3 letters instead

Tags: angular-material

this.Parentlist = this.Parentlist.filter((x: any) => x.id !== this.buDetails.data.id);
}

I need a filter for 3 letters instead of 1 letter I've written the above line for 1 letter filtter so need to alter for the 3 letters instead